# VBA Code to Hide Rows in a Table (More complicated than it sounds)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

**LAST POST WAS DELETED - "BEEN ASKED BEFORE" - PLEASE READ WHOLE THING :)**

Basically I have a large table (500 rows) and I need to only show the amount of rows based on the value in a certain cell (If the value in that cell is 123 then show only the top 123 rows). [Here is a picture of the top 25 rows of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmp6v.png)

*I want to accomplish this **without** writing 500 'if' statements like this:*

```
Private Sub PG1(ByVal Target As Range)
  If .Range("A1").Value = "123" Then
    Rows("124:500").EntireRow.Hidden = True
  End If
  If .Range("A1").Value = "124" Then
    Rows("125:500").EntireRow.Hidden = True
  End If
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: That's the best solution you could come up with? A basic tutorial on programing anything would show you there are better ways to approach this kind of problem `.Range("A" & .Range("A1").Value & ":A500").EntireRow.Hidden = True`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad sounds like a perfect answer. Why not post it as such?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Thanks for the comment. I am new to this so the patronizing isn't really appreciated but that seems like it is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.  You call it with `t()` technically.  I don't know what you need the target reference for, but this worked for me.

```
Sub t()
PG1 (Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"))
End Sub

Private Sub PG1(ByVal target As Range)
' Why do you need `target` at all?
Dim lastRow As Long
With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' CHANGE AS NEEDED
    lastRow = .Range("A1").Value
    .Range("A1:A" & lastRow).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    .Range("A" & lastRow + 1 & ":A500").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End With
End Sub
```

This is not relative either, it assumes that your table is literally in rows `1:500`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub PG1(ByVal Target As Range)
    .Range("A" & .Range("A1").Value & ":A500").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Without a `With` statement, what is the `.` linking to in `.Range()`?

Comment: OP didn't include it in his code, so I don't know...

Comment: I'm surprised it doesn't throw an error.  Thanks for clarifying though!